# How do I send send-keys command to vim dialog?

Tags: vim

I am trying to refresh a tmux buffer containing vim from another tmux pane in another session:

`nnoremap  <F8> :execute "tmux send-keys -t test:.left :e Enter e"<cr>`

The problem is I get the prompt to `[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (Q)uit, (A)bort:` and the `e` at the end of the command above is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, had to insert a delay in there. Used a function:

```
function! SendKeys()
   execute "silent !tmux send-keys -t test:.left :e Enter"
   sleep 1m
   execute "silent !tmux send-keys -t test:.left e"
endfunction
```